# Rest Web Service to download image & resize it if needed on linux system

Tags: java, rest, image-processing

My task is to create web service to download image & if needed, resize it according to required height & width as an optional parameters, for local system, i.e windows, code is working fine, but on server, i.e linux, showing null pointer exception, following is my code

```
 public File resizeImage(File file,String filePath,int width,int height) throws Exception {
        Graphics2D g = null;
        File file2 = File.createTempFile(file.getName(), FilenameUtils.getExtension(filePath));
        try{
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
            int w = img.getWidth();  
            int h = img.getHeight();  
            BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(width, height, img.getType());  
            g = dimg.createGraphics();  
            g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);  
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, w, h, null);
            ImageIO.write(dimg, FilenameUtils.getExtension(filePath), file2);
        } finally {
            g.dispose();  
        }
        return file2;
    }
```

Please help me for that,

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, query parameters are indeed optional, just check if they're null and if they're not you do the resize.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply, code is working fine, you really deserv +1

Comment: I'm glad it helped you :-). Could you mark the answer as 'accepted' if it has been helpful?

Comment: Oh yes i will, but can you help me a little more, the resize code is working fine on windows system, but is nit working on linux & givinh null pointer exception at "return response.build();", Can you help for that??

Comment: Maybe the library you are using is Windows only? If you want to check other libraries, read this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892725/java-good-and-free-library-to-resize-images